# Python extend the lifetime of a variable in the scope of the with keyword

Tags: python

Presume I have code that opens a file with the `with` keyword and I want it to stay open after closing under certain conditions.

so assuming the simplest function:

```
def do_sth():
  with open('/tmp/foobar') as f:
    # do anything to stop f from closing
```

is there a way to circumvent the python interpreter to call `f.__exit__()` ?
you can assume, that this should be applicable to any class implementing `__enter__` and `__exit__`.

So far I tried to replace f with another closable object like this:

```
d = open('/tmp/bsdf')
with open('/tmp/asdf') as f:
    d,f = f,d
print "f {}, d {}".format(f.closed, d.closed)
```

one potential use case would be to create a wrapper such that you can do:

```
with filehandle('foobar') as f:
  # do something

# don't close if filehandle returns sys.stdout.
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading [pep-0343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) I concluded that this is not supposed to be part of the semantics.

the only option I found is to write your own context manager that does a conditional release.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys

@contextmanager
def custom_open(filename, mode='r'):
    if filename is 'stdout':
        yield sys.stdout
    else:
        try:
            f = open(filename, mode)
        except IOError, err:
            yield None
        else:
            try:
                yield f
            finally:
                f.close()


with custom_open('stdout') as f:
    f.write('hello world\n')
print "f {}".format(f.closed)

with custom_open('/tmp/foobar', 'w+') as f:
    f.write('hello world\n')
print "f {}".format(f.closed)
```